# Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:8085

Tags: tomcat

I downloaded Apache Tomcat 7 to use with NetBeans 6.9.  I followed the installation as best as I could.  I think I did everything OK. when I tried to get to the Tomcat welcome screen but typing http://localhost:8085, which is the port i set when I installed Tomcat, I got the error Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:8085.  I even checked server.xml in the config folder to confirm the port which was incorrect at first (8005), but I made the correction to (8085)and I still get the error. I have something else in the standard 8080 port.

Any help will be appreciated

Jerry McLeod

Comment: Look in your catalina.log for a start up message like *INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080* to confirm the port.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know Tomcat is on port 8085?  Does `netstat -nat` show anything listening on port 8085?

Answer (score 0):

This is really not much info to go on, so we can only guess very basic problems.
Assuming the port is correct:

- Is the tomcat server actually running?
- Do you have any firewall software that would be preventing it from communicating?

Comment: I dont know how to tell if it is running.  All i know is the http://localhost:8085 procedure.  However, my server.xml file in the config folder has this statement - <Server port="8085" shutdown="SHUTDOWN"> in it. This is the port i established during installation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with another browser or `telnet localhost 8085` at the command line to see if you get a response?

Comment: Yes i have tried it with another browser and still no good.  After telneting localhost 8085 I received a could not open connection to host error.

Comment: This leads me to think that it's not actually connected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a default installation:

8080 is the http port you should try this. localhost:8080

8005 is the shutdown port. This listens for a string SHUTDOWN. And turns off the tomcat instance.  To do this you can test by typing

```
telnet localhost 8005
SHUTDOWN
```

The tomcat instance will then shut down.

The other port your likely to see in a default installation is 8009 this is an AJP port.
Basically this port is used to connect your tomcat instance with Apache httpd server or other http servers.

Answer (score -1):

Go to task manager and in processes or in services make sure that your program is running.
If not edit it and manually start the service or process