# Apache TomCat problems

Tags: apache, tomcat

Here is the situation.  I reinstalled NetBeans 6.9 to my desktop and the basic application is working fine as far as i can tell. During the installation I purposely loaded Tomcat and not Glassfish. It gave me that option.  Tomcat is loaded under my Program Files directory and i confirmed it by going to my control panel. I have a short application and trying to run and it tells me "Target server has not been set - Resolve missing server problem". When I go to solve this problem I have to add a server. I follow the instructions to add Tomcat 6 and I can't get to first base with it. I browse to the location where it is stored in my Program Files directory and when I get to the bin directory there are no files there to select (is this common).  Sometimes i get the Catalina not valid error, I am quite sure you are familiar with this error.

Could someone tell me why i am having some much trouble with this Tomcat server.  I did not have this trouble previously when I was using Glassfish. It should not be this complicated I would not think and i am following the instructions. Also, I checked my server.xml file and it indicated that the port was "8005".  How did this happen. I did not give it this port number during installation. How can I change it to 8080?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

JM

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is you're changing the wrong line in your server.xml.

Dont look at the `<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">`

The running port is configured via this line below.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" maxThreads="5" acceptCount="10"/>
```

Comment: Asked the same question again more or less http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337828/oops-google-chrome-could-not-connect-to-localhost8085